# Xcode 5 valid signing identity not found

Tags: ios, xcode

While I appreciate there's a hundred posts on here relating to this topic, after having read through those posts and nothing working for me, I've got no option but to start my own thread.

I have downloaded the certificates that are available on my companies enterprise account, added those to my keychain and generated and installed a provisioning profile that pairs with the downloaded certificates, yet I'm still getting the valid signing identity not found error?

I'm literally pulling my heart over this. I've removed and reinstalled certificates and also regenerated a provisioning profile and still no luck... Anyone any ideas?

Running XCode 5.0.2 on OSX Mavericks

[image: organizer]
[image: keychain]

Comment: can you show what provisioning profile you are using and the certificates for it ( basically a screenshot of them in build settings of the project )

Comment: Yea we definitely need some pictures to help you out.  Did you do it all through Xcode? using the organizer?

Comment: updated original posts - is this what you need?

Comment: Whenever I have problems like this I end up removing all the developer related certificates from the iPhone/ipad and the development Mac. I then reboot the MAC and let Xcode reinstall all the certs. I've struggled with issues like this for hours also...

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot of your certificate, I do not see a private key corresponding to the 'iPhone Developer' certificate. There must be a private key installed for the certificate and it should show up when you expand your certificate as shown in my screenshot:

[image]

You will have to generate a CSR, request for a new certificate, download and install it and verify you have a private key, then associate the certificate with the profile, redownload and install the profile.

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  It's a good idea to go through and follow Apple's directions precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bundle identifier same exactly with app ID and check your device selected in provisioning profile in your developer account.

I suggest you follow this tutorial step by step for your more understanding.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the iPhone Configuration Utility to make sure provisioning profiles are installed on your device.

[image]